# How to drive variable power (up to 1500w) to a grill heating element

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, electrical

I have a heating element like the following:

[image: heating element]

which is rated to 1500W. I need to be able to drive up to 1500W of power to it, but potentially less. I will be plugging it into a 120V wall outlet.

I am wondering what kind of components I need to make this happen at the lowest possible price point. :)

Thank you for your opinion

Comment: You can use a variac.

Comment: Cross-posted to EE.SE https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566719/how-to-drive-variable-power-up-to-1500w-to-a-grill-heating-element-from-a-120v

Comment: Why not a thermostat as in every oven?

Comment: @mart becasue they asked for a variable heater not on-off control

Comment: @TigerGuy The speed of heating/cooling of these makes the difference between the two academic, and unless the heater is used as a dummy load for testing some high-wattage  circuitry, temperature control tends to be a much better option than power control. A lot of people ask XY questions, seeking a solution to an entirely avoidable sub-problem they created in search of solution to their main problem; It's not really helping if you provide advice how to best file edges off a square peg the asker tries to fit in a round hole, instead of pointing out the convenient square hole next to it.

Comment: @SF. but the best answer is below, the standard electric element control used as in every electric cooktop.

Comment: @TigerGuy And it's also an on-off control, a tunable thermostat coupled with its own heating coil.

Comment: this is a possible XY problem ... you ask for help with what you consider to be a solution to an unstated problem, even though your solution may not be the optimum solution ... the reason why I say this, is the `but potentially less` statement ... it seems that you are thinking of reducing the current flowing through the element ... please describe the actual problem that you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a user adjustable knob, I would consider an infinite switch:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_switch, mounted in an electrical box,
You will want to use nickel-plated Hi Temperature Wire Terminals and Crimp Connectors, and HI-temp fiberglass or silicone insulated wire rated to 250-500°C
For example;
https://wcpsealers.com/HTML/wire%26lugs.html

I second enlisting the help of an electrician in your local area.

1500W is just above what a general purpose US 15A 120V outlet can supply,
and
It cannot be used on a US general purpose 15A circuit as the current will be over 12 Amps.
[See the National Electrical Code(NEC) NFPA 70;](https://nfpa.org/NEC/About-the-NEC/Free-online-access-to-the-NEC-and-other-electrical-standards)
210.21(B)(3)
It could be used on a US general purpose 20A circuit, typically in kitchens, bathrooms and laundry areas.

Consider using 230 Volt elements and controls (US Nominal 240V) as the US code allows this (NFPA 70 NEC 210.6) it and you will likely need a dedicated circuit either way.
There are more standard oven controls and elements available in '230' (240) Volt.

Answer (score 0):

Triac based light dimmer will do the job. It must be designed to stand 1500W incandescent light bulbs.

Constructing a safe one is far from trivial. A ready to assemble dimmer may be the easiest choice. "Rotary light dimmer 2000W for incandescent bulbs" is a generally available device. In advertisements there can stand SCR instead of triac.

Making the wiring and connections without making a fire bomb or electrocution device needs the knowledge and skills of a proper electrician.

BTW. The same triac based circuit principle is also used in vacuum cleaners and drilling machines to control speed

Comment: This is referred to as "phase control". It does generate conducted disturbances on the powerline at the AC power frequency (or 2x). For heating (vs light) this is usually unnecessary and something that switches less often could be considered more graceful